# Can't view answers and comments in the android app

Tags: bug, android-app

I'm having trouble viewing answers or comments in SE app (I can do other things, e.g., asking q's). I can view the snippet of the comment I get in my notifications, but not the full comment on the question. I'm using android based cellphone.

I'm using SE app v. 1.0.85 and Android v. 5.0.1

I'm adding 2 screenshots:

The first one shows this question. As you can see-I can't see any of your comments.

[image: 1st screen]

The second one shows you an answer I got on another question I asked. As you can see, I can't see the content of the answer.

[image]

In addition, I can tell you I have a lot of blank spaces between my question and the answers I get.

**Example**: I can't read your full comment (I can read only the brief I get in the " notification box ")... as you probably understand - I'm answering you from my cell using the app.

Comment: The team will need more information than this to help you out. What do you mean by "watching answers or comments"? What version of the app are you using? What version of Android? Yes, this is the right place for this question, but your question needs some more information.

Comment: For example i can't read your full comment (i can read only the brief i get in the " notification box ")... as you probably understand-im answering you from my cell using the app. I'll read your full comment later.. :)

Comment: Maybe a screenshot would help?

Comment: Perhaps you should load this question in a mobile browser? That way you can answer comments quicker and more completely.

Comment: I start driving, so i can't.. sorry!

Comment: @sagivmal No problem, do it after you  arrived.

Comment: I added more information :)

Comment: As a note for you, you don't need "thanks" or "edit" in your posts- Everyone can see your post was edited (provided it was after 5 minutes or an edit by another user or a comment by another user) by the link at the bottom of your post. They can also use this to see _what_ was edited. And "thanks" is unneeded here- We thank answerers with upvotes instead. (I know, you can't upvote yet on this site. You'll get there.) For more info on what we call "fluff" in posts, check out [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big white space when opening a question on Android app in RtL layout](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278793/big-white-space-when-opening-a-question-on-android-app-in-rtl-layout)

Comment: @Portal Great! it worked. BTW, do you know about any solution to this problem (meaning- leaving the rtl mode and use the SE app in a normal way)? .

Comment: The RtL is usually related to phone's language setting. If the language normally use right-to-left reading (e.g. Hebrew, Arabic), then it will use RtL layout, and unfortunately SE app is not optimized yet for that. I can only suggest to use different language... (Troublesome, I know..)