# Stack Overflow Android app displays huge empty gaps between answers and comments

Tags: bug, android-app

Consider:

[image: pic]

It's nearly impossible to read a thread that way, and I'm using Samsung Galaxy S8. I have this issue in the Stack Overflow app and in the Stack Exchange (version 1.0.94) app as well.

I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221541/huge-space-in-the-stack-exchange-android-app) question about the same bug, but it's from 2014, and I'm surprised this hasn't been fixed yet. Any idea?

It's also important to mention that I had this issue in my Samsung Galaxy S5 as well, from years back.

Comment: If the issue is exist for Stack Exchange Android-app too, please include the app version number to the post.

Comment: @Arulkumar version 1.0.94

Comment: I'm trying to recreate this but haven't been able to yet. Is it happening for you on every question? Is it happening routinely on one question, but not others? Any more info to help me in debugging this would be fantastic!

Comment: It happens on all threads.

Comment: [here's](https://s18.postimg.org/fx5t4tg4p/Image.jpg) and image from the starting top of this question, and [that's](https://s18.postimg.org/hv8ar0s2h/Image.jpg) an image from the bottom of this question.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi any good news? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the same issue with [Big white space when opening a question on Android app in RtL layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278793/big-white-space-when-opening-a-question-on-android-app-in-rtl-layout), only on Stack Overflow Android app.

This has been "fixed" on v1.0.4.

From Google Play's "What's New",

> This update fixes our app for devices with a right-to-left locale setting. Since the content of the app is all in English, **we now force left-to-right no matter the setting**.
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Yes! Finally!!!